# Is Landauer’s principle an approximation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, landauers-principle

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle), Landauer’s principle follows from the second law of thermodynamics. However, the second law of thermodynamics is an approximation: there is an extremely small probability that entropy decreases. Does it follow that Landauer’s principle is also an approximation, which holds almost always?

Comment: I think it is worse than that. The Wikipedia article mentions right at the top that the heat dissipating effect coming from non reversible computing and being claimed by the Landauer principle is at the order of $10^{-6}$ of the energy that modern computers are dissipating anyway. Moreover, the article gives quite a few references how controversial the topic still is. For a good overview about various notions of entropy see for example this [PSE post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle).

Comment: Sorry wrong link. This [PSE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/141321/what-is-the-conceptual-difference-between-gibbs-and-boltzmann-entropies).