# Can reversible computers really perform truly reversible computations in practice?

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-computer, reversibility

Someone once told me that with reversible computers there is no energy cost for the computation itself, there is only a cost for running the hardware. But is this true in practice, or is it only an idealization?

Comment: "In theory, theory and practice are the same. In practice, they are different."

Comment: Maybe a better fit for [cs.se].

Comment: You are asking about the [Landauer principle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/733082/304394). Imho this is an ineradicable myth coming from a confusion of Shannon entropy with thermodynamical entropy.

Comment: Nobody has built a reversible computer yet. In principle, we know there is a theoretical minimum energy cost for non-reversible computations, and we know reversible computers could be a loophole to bypass it. But nobody's actually built one that does. Our best computers today still use zillions of times more energy than the theoretical limit